# How to read audio from a 3.5mm jack?

Tags: amplifier, audio, adc

A seemingly simple question that has a myriad of answers all over the web.

Goal: I am trying to design a device that is able to read analog audio and extract frequency distribution. I do not care about absolute amplitude, only relative amplitude, i.e. I am only trying to compare the intensity of certain frequencies in a given audio signal.

Why the other answers don't cut it: All the answers that I have found don't seem to address the issue of differing peak to peak voltage  device to device and volume setting to volume setting. My device is going to sit between source and speaker, so it needs to be able to recalibrate when volume is changed. It will also be used with at least three different devices: my desktop, laptop, and phone. The P2P voltage at max volume on the headphone outputs of these 3 devices varies from hundreds of mV to 4V. My understanding is that there exist other devices with P2P voltages as high as 12V. I would like to design with those devices in mind as well.

I intend to use the ADC on my MCU with range 0-3V3.

If it wasn't clear already, I am by no means an electrical engineer and my understanding is fairly limited and I have not been able to devise a way to make this work. The issue the way I see it is that I need a circuit that will adjust gain and dc offset appropriately based on the source.

My thoughts so far: My current solution is to use two opamps as a peak detector and use that to add a dc offset to the signal using another opamp as an inverting amplifier. The gain of this amplifier will be adjusted using a digital potentiometer that is being controlled by the MCU. The amplifier starts at max gain and keeps stepping down until the peak of the signal is less than 3V3. The solution has the benefit that with a push of a button, I can reset the peak detector and instruct the MCU to begin recalibration. I am not at all married to this solution (I am asking how to best solve my goal, not how to fix the solution).

[image: My Solution]

However, I'm unsure how to protect my MCU from being damaged by input voltages greater than 3V3 (since the calibration method relies on starting above 3V3 and coming down).

Comment: What power supply voltages do you have in your design?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, it doesn't really matter what supply voltages are being used.  If the input signal is protectively clipped to the supply voltages then the devices are protect regardless of the specific voltage.

Comment: @RichardCrowley -- I'm asking to get an idea of what parts can be used in this design :) (being on single-supply 5V or 3.3V for the analog side is a different constraint than being able to run your AFE off of +/-15V, even with the ADC in both cases being a 0-3.3V unit)

Comment: I have a +12V, a +3V3, and 0V in my current design. I had planned on the opamps running on +12V/0V and the MCU (and the ADC since that is built in) running at 3V3/0V.

Comment: Not an expert, just throwing in the idea that what you describe must be how an AGC works, isn't it?

Comment: Hadn't come across those in my searching, you've given me something else to research. However, based on my brief reading into AGCs it appears that they preserve frequency but distort amplitude? I want to be able to tell the difference in intensity of various frequencies not only in a given time slice but also over multiple slices. Once calibrated, the unit shouldn't change the gain until recalibrated.

Comment: Can you get a -12V supply in your design? (Doesn't have to be beefy, just has to be there -- 25mA will do the job quite nicely here)

Comment: Not quite sure how. This thing will be powered off of a 12V DC adapter (the power bricks that are almost ubiquitous). I have a DCDC switching regulator stepping it down to 3v3. I don't see how I could add -12V *easily*. THough I guess it could be done with some additional design work. Why is it necessary? Won't the opamps do just fine on 12v/0v since I don't care about the negative part of the signal?

Comment: @ApoorvaKharche -- having a dual supply opens up your options re: IC selection.  An inverting chargepump or DC-DC can easily generate -12V from your +12V, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. It is very unlikely that over-voltage audio signals will cause any kind of "damage" to the CPU or the ADC. The worst that can happen is that the signal will be "clipped" or "flat-topped" which will cause distortion.  So you can write the firmware for your application to look for an extended sequence of minimum (zero) or maximum (your did you reveal your digital resolution?) and reduce the gain of the input stage. Or conversely detect an average audio level that is too low, and increase the gain, etc.  You may be anticipating "problems" that aren't really "problems".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't yet decided on a good balance of sample rate and resolution, so I left that part out of the question. I don't think that's too big of a deal, mostly just a tangential issue that I will need to figure out based on some more data sampling and basic math. Yeah, I felt I might be overthinking this. Very few devices are going to have extremely high voltages, and most will probably be close to 500mV-1V RMS. But I have had too many projects fail because I forget edge cases exist, and so I like to consider them and design for them if possible.

Comment: Yes, it is very admirable to consider the edge cases and you are exactly right to do so.  However you are working with an incorrect assumption that high-amplitude input signals will be "harmful" in any significant way.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why they won't be. Is it because there isn't any real current actually running into the ADC (provided there is a pull down)?

Comment: Analog to digital converters need very little signal current to operate properly. So you can use a relative high-value series input resistor to reduce input over-voltage fault current. AND use diode(s) to CLAMP the input signal to a safe level.  If you detect that the input signal is being clamped by the protection circuit, then you simply reduce the level by means of your digital pot.

Comment: I didn't even think of putting a diode clamp on the out end of it. In hindsight, that was a pretty obvious solution. Especially since it doesn't need to be very precise, just within the tolerance of the MCU GPIO pins. And it makes detecting clipping a lot easier too if you use a transistor for one of the clamps and set up an interrupt on a digital GPIO pin. Thanks.

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment, but in case it wasn't obvious, I was thinking of using a diode and a BJT as a clamp instead of a single zener diode. It saves me a little bit of complexity in the firmware. With the BJT, I just reduce the gain on an interrupt instead of actively checking for any particular condition. I'm thinking of something like: http://i.imgur.com/V1FQkjS.png It seems a little fishy and I would try it out in a SPICE sim, but I've been a little frustrated with LTspice, and I don't have access to PSPICE again until August.

Comment: Using a transistor far "downstream" seems more complex and more dangerous.  Using simple diode clamps at the INPUT (before any active circuit) protects you against over-voltage.  Using that transistor way down-stream does nothing for protection.

Comment: I realized that, eventually. Like stated above, I have no formal learning and mostly just floundering through most of this analog circuits stuff. Right now my plan looks pretty different than the one earlier. Biggest change I have made is assuming that the input signal will be 6V pp at most, and just flash an angry LED at the user if it's more than that. I've gotten rid of peak detector because it's superfluous if I'm clamping the signal right before the ADC. I've moved my opamps onto +3v3/-3v3 instead of 12V/0V and I've added two zeners before the first opamp.

Comment: What I've got so far: http://tinyurl.com/h4xd979 Undoubtedly still room for improvement. And I'm not quite sure how I would go about flashing angry LEDs when the Zener protection at the start of the circuit is triggered, there isn't nearly enough current flowing through there to be able to just stick an LED in there. Well, there shouldn't be? I'm not entirely sure. I also had to move the digital pot since all pdip pots seem to have the same max voltage on spec on their pins. That was the primary reason to exclude any signal greater than 6v pp.